# É possível trabalhar com repositório local "comunitário" em Git?

Tags: git, github

Imagine que eu tenha um repositório remoto no Github, mas também gostaria de replicá-lo em um servidor local, desta forma permitindo que minha equipe trabalhe (e compartilhe código) mesmo sem acesso remoto.

E, por exemplo, ao fim do dia ou da semana, seria feito um commit deste repositório "comunitário" local, para o repositório oficial, remoto.

Pelo que eu pesquisei, é possível replicar um repositório na minha própria máquina e *comitar* "localmente", mas só eu veria esses meus *commits*. Não achei nada a respeito de um repositório local "comunitário".

É possível fazer isso com Git?

Comment: Pelo que sei você pode instalar um servidor git em alguma máquina e realizar os commits nele e também acredito que depois pegar dele e enviar ao github; Aqui na empresa temos um git instalado no servidor mas não usamos github ainda...; Não sei se é bem essa a solução que você gostaria...

Comment: É basicamente o que o colega disse acima, você instala o servidor GIT no servidor e comita para ele como se estivesse comitando para o git e depois desse servidor sobe para o github por exemplo da mesma forma, sinto muito por não ter mais detalhes técnicos mas a lógica é essa.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

De alguma forma o acesso será remoto. Mesmo que remoto não saia do prédio onde você está. Até mesmo se o acesso seja feito via SSH, por exemplo, será remoto. Então estritamente local fica complicado. Mas acho que o termo local apenas não foi bem usado. Pelo que entendi você quer que tenha um repositório remoto mas que não dependa da internet. De outra forma não vejo como as pessoas poderiam acessar o seu computador.

Para resolver isso basta criar um servidor de Git. Ele é essencialmente um repositório Git rodando de uma forma que o acesso remoto possa ser feito. De uma certa forma você está criando seu próprio GitHub, ainda que de forma mais simples e limitada.

A documentação "oficial" fala sobre o uso do [Git como servidor](http://git-scm.com/book/ca/v1/Git-on-the-Server) ([guia de configuração em português](http://git-scm.com/book/pt-br/v1/Git-no-Servidor-Configurando-o-Servidor)). Após ele ser configurado corretamente o uso do repositório passa ser igual a um servidor remoto fora da sua rede. Claro que pode ser restrito para acessar apenas internamente.

Algumas pessoas preferem soluções um pouco mais prontas e mais completas como o [Gitorious](http://getgitorious.com/) ou [GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/) ou [Gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) ou [Gitblit](http://gitblit.com/) ou ainda comprar a [versão enterprise do GitHub](https://enterprise.github.com/). E tem ainda algumas outras opções como o [Indefero](http://projects.ceondo.com/p/indefero/) ou [SCM Manager](https://www.scm-manager.org/).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futur](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md)a.