# Qual a diferença entre o repositório remoto do GitHub e o remoto do meu servidor dedicado?

Tags: git, servidor, github, repository

No GitHub podemos criar repositórios remotos, e ao fazermos ganhamos um determinado conjunto de funcionalidades administrativas sob este repositório, umas dessas funcionalidades é a possibilidade do administrador revisar os *commits* recebidos, revisá-los e decidir por aplicá-los ao projeto ou não (dentre outras).

Há a possibilidade de criar um repositório remoto em um servidor dedicado linux. Minha dúvida é se ao faze-lo eu ganho as mesmas funcionalidades oferecidas pelo GitHub (tal como a citada, por exemplo).

Na prática quais as diferenças entre ambos repositórios remotos?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

De forma geral não ganha essas funcionalidades. Não confunda Git com GitHub. No seu servidor você só tem o Git, não tem nada que o GitHub tem. Nada impede de você adicionar funcionalidades no seu servidor. O que vai instalar ou fazer na mão para tê-las é problema é seu.

Note que você até pode fazer seu servidor conversar com o GitHub. Repositórios Git não se distinguem em cliente e servidor, exceto pela configuração de acesso.

Algumas pessoas gostam de usar o GitLab no seu próprio servidor, mas tem outras soluções. Já [respondi sobre isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51917/101).

Comment: Então em essência um repositório remoto no dedicado é igual ao repositório no GitHub, porém o GitHub oferece uma camada de funcionalidades mais robusta sob este repositório, já o repositório remoto no meu dedicado não possui esta camada de funcionalidades. Esta é a ideia ?

Comment: O repositório é idêntico, é como um compilador C++, compila qualquer programa em C++ igual, muda se você está usando no Visual Studio, no Eclipse, Code::Blocks, CLion, Vim com GCC, XCode com Clang, etc., mas a base é padrão.

Comment: Obrigado pelos esclarecimentos amigo, excelente explicação. E agradeço ainda por compartilhar o link de sua resposta anterior, foi de grande ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Não, não ganha. O github é um site. Git é uma ferramenta.

O Github simplesmente usa um backend para ler as informações do repositório Git e mostra de maneira bonitinha pra você.

Se você usar o VS Code ou Visual Studio, vai ver que eles usam também um layout costumizado para mostrar informações do Git. Ou seja, é uma implementação específica de quem usa.

Basicamente, muitas das funcionalidades básicas e úteis que o Github te mostra no layout deles você pode acessar do console da sua máquina, rodando os comandos do Git.

**Exemplos:**

`git ls-files`: mostra todos os arquivos incluídos no seu repositório. Coisas ignorada não são listadas.

`git diff`: mostra a diferença entre as versões dos arquivos. Se você especificar mais parâmetros, pode comparar com um commit ou arquivo específico.

`git status`: mostra os arquivos alterados, incluídos ou deletados, em relação ao último commit.

`git checkout nomedobranch`: muda o ramo de trabalho atual.